# Downgrade hardware compatibility

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I need to run VMware virtual machine that was created on on VMware version 16 in VMware workstation 15. Is it possible to convert virtual machine in order to run it on lower version workstation?

Comment: A google search on "vmware downgrade v16 to v15" found https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/VM-downgrade-from-16-to-15/td-p/2823699

Comment: loosely related anecdote: so back in the olden days, we had a ESXI cluster (I want to say 5.5 or 6.0), and managed it with vSphere Client.  Then one day, an admin (who is perhaps the least competent IT person I've ever worked with) discovered a right click option labeled "Update Virtual Machine Hardware". He didn't realize that once the hardware had been upgraded, we would no longer be able to edit hardware settings on the VM through vSphere client. He upgraded 70 VMs before we found out. Morale: VMWare can be serious about versioning. do your homework first.

Comment: If you have already upgraded the hardware compatibly then what you want isn’t possible

Answer (score 1):

> I need to run VMware virtual machine that was created on on VMware
> version 16 in VMware workstation 15. Is it possible to convert virtual
> machine in order to run it on lower version workstation?

Yes, with VMware Workstation, you can do this. I am not sure about ESX but it works in Workstation.

I took a Windows 98 machine at Hardware Compatibility Level 9 and converted it (making a Clone) to Hardware Compatibility level 6.

Both machines work, so you should not experience difficulty. Always (a) make a clone and (b) have a backup when changing compatibility.

VMware V15 is close enough to VMware V16 that the change should work. I did the conversion to lower level on VMware V16.

Original machine:

[image]

Clone machine at lower level.

[image]

Here is the VMware Setup to change Hardware Level.

[image]